# Selecting data that appears on 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I’m trying to figure out how to select data only if it appears in two different tables. Here’s the table structure:

Here is the `clientInfo` table:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Name | Region ID  | other info                 |
--------------------------------------------------
| Bob  |    12      | likes cookies              |
--------------------------------------------------
| Joe  |     20     | scuba diver                |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the `regions` table:

```
----------------------------------------
| Location   | Region ID  | Published  |
----------------------------------------
| California |    12      | 1          |
----------------------------------------
| Oregon     |     4      | 1          |
----------------------------------------
| Washington |     8      | 0          |
----------------------------------------
| Colorado   |    20      | 1          |
----------------------------------------
```

I want to use a query to make a selection via a pull down menu that selects a state only if it’s published AND a client belongs to one of those states.

Edit: In my rush yesterday, I realized that I didn't make my question fully clear. I wanted to be able to have a pull down menu of the states to be populated as a search parameter. So based on the data above, the web page's pull down menu would populate the pull down menu according to which states actually had clients that belonged to them.

```
------------------------------     -------------
| Choose State to Search | ▼ |     |  Search   |
------------------------------     -------------
|    California              |
|    Colorado                |
------------------------------
```

How would I word this mysql query statement?

Comment: I just got back to work this morning and just wanted to thank all of you guys! You're awesome!

Comment: hi everyone, I added an edit to the question. Sorry about the confusion. Should've finished the question properly, but I had somewhere I needed to go yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `exists`:

```
select r.*
from regions r
where r.published = 1 and
      exists (select 1 from clientinfo ci where r.region_id = ci.region_id);
```

Comment: What's half a minute for the appropriate answer, +1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Easy. Use a `LEFT JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT Name, Location, Published
FROM clientInfo ci
LEFT JOIN regions reg ON (ci.Region_ID = reg.Region_ID)
;
```

I am assuming your column titled `Region ID` is actually `Region_ID` since I can’t imagine that having an empty space in it.

Comment: This query is going to return all locations in the `clientinfo` table.  A simple `inner join` should work with the `where` criteria for published, but it might require the use of `distinct`.

Comment: I'll check out info on LEFT JOIN. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT location
FROM regions r
WHERE published = 1
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM clientInfo c
        WHERE r.RegionId = c.RegionId)
```

You can also achieve the same result with a `JOIN` or `IN`, but I prefer the way this reads.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of researching once you guys let me know of LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN, this is what ended up working for me

```
mysql_query(SELECT DISTINCT regions.location FROM regions INNER JOIN clientInfo ON regions.region_id=clients.region_id)
```

This ended up displaying the region_id only once (DISTINCT) regardless of how many times it showed up on the clientInfo table.

Thank you everyone for all your help!